# Unity custom editor serialize Vector3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to run the following:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(MyObject))]
public class MyObjectEditor : Editor {

    public override void OnInspectorGUI(){
        MyObject t = (MyObject)target;
        Mesh mesh = t.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
        Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(vertices);
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Argument `#1' cannot convert `UnityEngine.Vector3[]' 
expression to type `UnityEditor.SerializedProperty'
```

What can I do to put a `Vector3[]` in the `PropertyField` without having to put it in the `MyObject` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Vector3[]` type is not a `SerializedProperty`, you can not use the `PropertyField` method. However, you can use [`Vector3Field`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.Vector3Field.html):

```
for(int i = 0; i < mesh.vertices.Length; i++)
{
    mesh.vertices[i] = EditorGUILayout.Vector3Field("Vertice " + i, mesh.vertices[i]);
}
```